# Does a Pact of the Blade warlock need to make a roll when summoning their pact weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock

My DM and I are having a disagreement over how the pact weapon from Pact of the Blade (PotB) is summoned.

Specifically, as a Hexblade with PotB, when I choose to summon my pact weapon as whatever - sword, axe, anything - do I have to roll a d20 to see if I  successfully call it to me, regardless of whether I'm changing its form or if I'm recalling its previous form?

I've done some looking into the subject and haven't found a single reference to any such role being necessary. The description of Pact of the Blade (under the [Pact Boon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#PactBoon-389) feature) states:

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your empty hand.
> You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you
> create it [...]

Am I missing something?

His view seems to be PotB is the same as the pact I've made with my Patron (aka simply the fact I'm a warlock and that's the backstory of how we have/do magic) and thus just as I need a DC to cast, say, *eldritch blast*, or any other spell, I need one to call/summon my PotB pact weapon.

Do I need to roll any dice when I summon my pact weapon?

Comment: What do you mean by "DC to cast Eldritch Blast"?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @nathiel_damnlocke It seems from what you say that your GM is taking your patron's gifts as optional for the features attached to your Warlock, depending on whether you pass a DC. Can you explain this further please? Is it a Charisma DC or another stat, or a straight d20 roll? Also, do clerics have the same when deriving magic from their god, or druids from nature? Thank.

Answer (score 23):

There is nothing like that in the actual rules, you do not need to throw anything to summon the pact weapon. It is just as you yourself quote, if you do it in a battle it costs an action (so you may want to keep a summoned pact weapon in a scabbard always).

Most DMs would be inclined to house-rule the other way, making summoning easier (a bonus action or an object interaction), because it's Cool to summon the weapon in the battle, instead of drawing it from a scabbard lika an ordinary weapon. Anyway, if your DM insists on the summoning being unreliable, just keep the weapon summoned and in a scabbard.

---

About Hexblade patron and Pact of the Blade pact boon: these are separate.  You can pick Pact of the Blade with any patron, and you can pick any boon with Hexblade. They are separate features with very little interacation (Hex Warrior just allows you to use CHA with any summoned weapon). The major defining features of Hexblade are the Hex, and using CHA for weapon attacks.

---

Then you seem to imply you are testing against your *own* spell DC? If that's indeed what you do, well, that's kinda... to be frank, it's plain stupid, as the DC becomes harder as you level up (proficiency bonus). Spell DC is what *others* roll when they try to resist your spells (and *only* those which call for a saving throw). But maybe you didn't mean this.

Also, spellcasting DC does not interact with Eldritch Blast in any way. With EB you do a *ranged spell attack* (for Warlock: d20 + proficiency bonus + CHA bonus), against the Armor Class of the target.  Just read the spell description, and read the combat rules in the PHB (there *are* ambiguous bits in the rules, sure, but this is not one of them).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, especially the "Keep it in a scabbard" idea if he insists on rolling for the summon. Have to admit i thought the idea of rolling against myself was as you said stupid myself, hence the debate we're having. He's a great DM dont get me wrong but when i heard that I felt I had to look into it for that reason.

Also the extra info on DC is appreciated, as im a relatively new player to DnD. Might've been using the term DC wrong to be honest.

Comment: @NathielDamnLocke You can read a bit about DC [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AbilityChecks) in the basic rules, maybe it helps a bit.

Comment: @NathielDamnLocke Yeah, even if D&D 5th is relatively simple, it's easy to get things wrong, and then easy to get "stuck" on the wrong ruling. Also house rules are generally fine if they have a reason, but this sounds like just making Warlock (or all spellcasters, with that extra check thing?) weak and should be reversed.

Answer (score 10):

### No

You’ve already listed the relevant rule here. You can use your action to create a pact weapon. No ifs or buts. No DC. No dice rolling. You use your action, it happens.

As a side note, you don’t need to pass a DC to cast Eldritch Blast, for example. You use your action, you blast something. You do need to roll some dice here, but that is to determine whether or not you hit your target with it - it's a spell attack so you make a spell attack roll.  You don't roll to see whether or not you manage to cast the spell at all.